# No matching distribution found for Django==2.2

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am deploying a django app on a digital ocean droplet server that I developed using Django version 2.0.
Using Putty to SSH into my ubuntu server, I try to upgrade using `pip install Django==2.2`. I get the following error message:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.2 (from 
  versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 
  1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 
  1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 
  1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 
  1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 
  1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 
  1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 
  1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 
  1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 
  1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 
  1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 
  1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 
  1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 
  1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 
  1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 
  1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 
  1.11.18, 1.11.20)
  No matching distribution found for Django==2.2
```

Which is obviously not true. What am I missing here to upgrade?
I saw a similar post from awhile ago when someone was getting the same error message, but that was because they were searching for a version that was not released yet. The version I am trying to get is clearly available.

Before I tried to upgrade Django I did:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-django
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pip` is usually the package manager for Python-2.x. Django-1.11 is the last version of Django that works with Python-2.x: Django-2.0, only works on Python-3.4 or higher, as is specified in the [documentation on installing Django [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django).

Therefore the package manager can *not* find Django-2.2, hence the error. You likely want to use Python-3.x anyway. So you can install the package with the package manager for Python-3.x: `pip3`:

```
pip3 install Django==2.2
```