# Problem upgrading django doesn't show latest version

Tags: python, django

```
 pip install --upgrade django==2.2.7
Collecting django==2.2.7
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2.7 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20, 1.11.21, 1.11.22, 1.11.23, 1.11.24, 1.11.25, 1.11.26)
No matching distribution found for django==2.2.7
```

I am having problem upgrading

Comment: what is your python version? looks like you are using python 2.

Comment: Looks like you are working with Python-2.x. Django-2.0 and further only work with Python-3.x.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678695/no-matching-distribution-found-for-django-2-2/55678911#55678911

Comment: i think you are using old version of python

Comment: can you please tell your python version you can check via type this command `python --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using python 2.7 which does not support this version of Django,*the last version to support Python 2.7 is Django 1.11 LTS*.
 
**If you're using Python 3.* and still facing the same issue** 
You should upgrade your **pip** tool and **setuptools** before installing the latest version of Django.

```
pip3 install pip setuptools -U

pip3 install django==2.2.7 -U
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
   pip3 install django==2.2.7
```

But I think your problem is you use global Python/Pip for your project.